# Gridview sorting method - Numbers being sorted as strings - How to change the datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, numbers

I have a DataTable that I bind to a GridView and I would like to be able to click the column header to sort that column. I was able to achieve this functionality with the following methods:

```
 private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
 private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";
 public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
 {
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection) ViewState["sortDirection"];                
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; } 
}


protected void suiteReport_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;

    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING); 
    }   

}

private void SortGridView(string sortExpression,string direction)
{

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["QueryTable"];

    DataView dv = new DataView(dt); 
    dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;         

    suiteReport.DataSource = dv;
    suiteReport.DataBind();         
}
```

My problem is that all of my columns are sorted as if they are strings. Which leads to numbers such as 900 being considered "larger" than 50000. I realize that the problem is the fact they are beings sorted as strings, but I am unsure how to change that.

I create my columns dynamically, and here is where I create the boundfields.

```
 foreach (string s in headers)
 {
 BoundField bc = new BoundField();
 bc.HeaderText = s;
 bc.DataField = s.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
 bc.DataFormatString = "{0:C0}";
 bc.ItemStyle.Width = 125;

 if (s.StartsWith("S") || s.StartsWith("I"))
     bc.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
 else
     bc.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
 bc.SortExpression = s.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

 suiteReport.Columns.Add(bc);
 }
```

How/Where should I change the datatype?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your datasource before binding it to grid view. How you build grid view fields shouldn't make any difference. Make sure that columns' types in 'dt' DataTable from view state are correct (not all of them are type of string) and use linq:

```
private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
    {

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["QueryTable"];

        if (direction == ASCENDING)
        {
            suiteReport.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x[sortExpression]);
        }
        else
        {
            suiteReport.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x[sortExpression]);
        }

        suiteReport.DataBind();
    }
```

This assumes that sortExpression is the same as particular column's name in dt DataTable.

Comment: You're right, my columns were not correct. I fixed this when creating the columns of the table. Before, I was doing dt.Columns.Add("column1"). I realized that if I did dt.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(int)), my problem was solved. 

Thank you